# Combinatorics: Chess Board Example - Forbidden Positions

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, proof-explanation, derangements

I am struggling to answer the question below and I don't have any idea how I would prove this after getting the answer. Could someone help please? Thanks

In how many ways can 6 non-attacking rooks be placed on a 7x7 chessboard, with forbidden positions being the diagonal line from the top left corner to the bottom right corner (so 7 forbidden positions)? (Caution: we are asking for 6 non-attacking rooks, not 7). Write your answer in terms of derangement numbers and prove that your answer is correct (Proof has to be either using induction or a combinatorics proving method).

Comment: What have you tried? Have you expressed it in terms of derangements?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You want a permutation that is either:
1. A complete derangement -> How many are there? How many formations does each permutation yield?
2. Have 1 fixed point, the rest is a derangement ->  How many are there? How many formations does each permutation yield?

Hence, there are "Fill this in yourself" formations

Now, prove that any formation satisfying your conditions must satisfy either one of the above conditions.

Comment: Thanks Calvin for your answer, but I am having a hard time implementing the directions you have provided. Could you please show me how it is done?

Comment: @Alex Show your work. What have you done, where are you stuck? You can do so by editing your problem if the space in comments is too small.

Comment: I created a set of 7 slots, but having only 6 numbers in the set (from 1-6); thus, having 1 empty slot in the set. The slots represent the number of rows of the chessboard and the numbers/digits in the set represent the different non-attacking rooks. Then, I represented the forbidden spots on the chessboard as the numbers in the set that are not in their natural positions. In this case, there are 7 forbidden spots and the chessboard is 7x7, so how can I know the number of digits in the set that should not be in their natural positions? Also, how can we connect this to derangement number?

Comment: How have you used my hints to guide how you approach this problem? E.g. Look at 1. How would you answer both questions?

Comment: For 1, I think there are 6 numbers that should be considered for finding derangement number if that's what you mean. Also, I am not sure of the answer for your second question for Problem 1. I think you might be misunderstanding me for someone who knows enough combinatorics to solve this. Although I am trying my best, I really can't see a way to solve this with the knowledge that I have, but I would like to know how it is solved. Also, I really appreciate you providing questions for me to answer (step by step), but I really don't know the answers to them. Do you mind guiding me through them?

Comment: 1. if you're given a complete derangement, say $1\rightarrow 2, 2 \rightarrow 3, 3 \rightarrow 4, 4 \rightarrow 5, 5 \righarrow 6, 6 \rightarrow 7, 7 \rightarrow 1$, how can we relate that to non-attacking rooks that are not on the diagonal? How can we related that to 6 non-attacking rooks (formation) that are not on the diagonal? How many formations can we derive from this 1 derangement?